# Select rows from DataFrame where ID count is greater than X

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which a column that contains an ID. This ID represents a person and can be present many times:

```
        col_id    col2     col3     col4....
row1      1
row2      1
row3      2
row4      3
row5      3
row6      3
row7      1
row8      7
```

I need to return a new dataframe where the value_counts of the ID column is greater than, say 2.

New dataframe:

```
         col_id    col2     col3     col4....
row1      1
row2      1
row3      3
row4      3
row5      3
row6      1
```

This new dataframe contains rows where the ID count is greater than 2 only.

**Edit**

From here I need to separate the data by ID. Ideally I would like a solution where I have a dataframe for each ID:

Dataframe 1

```
    col_id   col2    col3    col4....
r1     1
r2     1
r3     1
```

Dataframe 2

```
    col_id   col2    col3    col4....
r1     2
r2     2
r3     2
```

Dataframe 3

```
    col_id   col2    col3    col4....
r1     3
r2     3
r3     3
```

Is it possible to join these into one large dataframe? So I can have  a new column, called 'index' that holds the rows for ID==1, ID==2, etc:

```
index
  1        col_id   col2    col3    col4....
       r1     1
       r2     1
       r3     1



index
  2       col_id   col2    col3    col4....
      r1     2
      r2     2
      r3     2


    index
       3      col_id   col2    col3    col4....
         r1     3
         r2     3
         r3     3
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for `Series` with same size like original DataFrame, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('col_id')['col_id'].transform('size') > 2]
print (df)
      col_id
row1       1
row2       1
row4       3
row5       3
row6       3
row7       1
```

If performance is not important or small `DataFrame` is possible use [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df = df.groupby('col_id').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)
```

EDIT: For separate DataFrames by `col_id` is possible create dictionary of DataFrames:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('col_id')))
print (dfs[1])
      col_id
row1       1
row2       1
row7       1

print (dfs[2])
      col_id
row3       2

print (dfs[3])
      col_id
row4       3
row5       3
row6       3
```

Possible, but non pythonic solution with globals, not recommended use (only for fun):

```
for i, df in df.groupby('col_id'):
    globals()['df{}'.format(i)] =  df

print (df1)
      col_id
row1       1
row2       1
row7       1
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Is there a way to return unique dataframes for each id? So return a single dataframe where ID == 1, and then where ID == 2, etc?

Comment: It close. I would like the dataframes to be joined together by a new column called index

Comment: @Muzz - in sample data what is index for `7` ? It is `4` or `7` ? If `7`, do you need `df = pd.concat(dfs)` or `df = df.sort_values('col_id')` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189808/discussion-between-muzz-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go ahead with your `value_counts()` method, then follow -

```
# Creating a dictionary using value_counts()
items = df.col_id.value_counts().to_dict().items()

# Filtering only those rows where duplicate entries occur more than n
n = 2
df = df[df.col_id.isin([key for key, val in items if val > n])]
```